# Passing data from local file using json

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I am trying to pass data to labels from my JSON file onto a simple ViewController but I don't know where to actually pass that data. Would I be able to just add to my `setDataToJson` method or would I add the data in my `viewDidLoad` method?

here is my code

```
@interface NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:(NSString*)fileLocation;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary(JSONCategories)

+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:(NSString*)fileLocation{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
    __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error != nil) return nil;
    return result;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize name;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)setDataToJson{

    NSDictionary *infomation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:@"Test.json"];
    name.text = [infomation objectForKey:@"AnimalName"];//does not pass data
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is the way you're trying to retrieve your file. In order to do it right, you should find first its path in the bundle. Try something like this:

```
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:(NSString*)fileLocation{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[fileLocation stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[fileLocation pathExtension]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                                options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    // Be careful here. You add this as a category to NSDictionary
    // but you get an id back, which means that result
    // might be an NSArray as well!
    if (error != nil) return nil;
    return result;
}
```

After doing that and once your view is loaded, you should be able to set your labels by retrieving the json like this:

```
-(void)setDataToJson{
    NSDictionary *infomation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:@"Test.json"];
    self.name.text = [infomation objectForKey:@"AnimalName"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setDataToJson];
}
```

Comment: Would I change my nsdictionary function if I wanted to get information from an array of data in the Json file
`self.lat.text = [[infomation valueForKey:@"Location"] valueForKey:@"Latitude"];` this is what I have and this is what the JSON looks like
`"Location": [
               {
               "Longitude": 0,
               "Latitude": 0
               }
               ],`
and when I run it it says `-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Then you should do something like this: `self.lat.text = [[[information valueForKey:@"Location"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Latitude"];`

Comment: okay I tried that and now it says `-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]` instead of NSArray. hmmmm

Comment: Ah, of course, it's a number and we have to convert it first. Try this: `self.lat.text = [[[[information valueForKey:@"Location"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Latitude"] stringValue];`

Comment: Note that it's unsafe to check an error instance returned by reference; instead, check the method's return value. From Apple's *Error Handling Programming Guide*: "Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure by directly returning `nil` or `NO`, you should always check that the return value is `nil` or `NO` before attempting to do anything with the `NSError` object."

Answer (score 1):

It should be `valueForKey` instead.

Example:

```
name.text = [infomation valueForKey:@"AnimalName"];
```