# How to extract value from dictionary using objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have the below dictionary and I want to extract the date and `number_of_movement`.

```
{
    id = 0;
    jsonrpc = "2.0";
    result =     {
        fetalMovements =         {
            "10|22|2014-08-04 00:00:00" =             {
                date =                 {
                    date = "2014-08-04 00:00:00";
                    timezone = "Europe/Prague";
                    "timezone_type" = 3;
                };
                "fetal_movement_id" = 10;
                "number_of_movement" = 3;
                "pregnancy_id" = 22;
            };
            "11|22|2014-08-03 00:00:00" =             {
                date =                 {
                    date = "2014-08-03 00:00:00";
                    timezone = "Europe/Prague";
                    "timezone_type" = 3;
                };
                "fetal_movement_id" = 11;
                "number_of_movement" = 3;
                "pregnancy_id" = 22;
            };
            "12|22|2014-08-03 00:00:00" =             {
                date =                 {
                    date = "2014-08-03 00:00:00";
                    timezone = "Europe/Prague";
                    "timezone_type" = 3;
                };
                "fetal_movement_id" = 12;
                "number_of_movement" = 3;
                "pregnancy_id" = 22;
            };
        };
    };
}
```

I use this code and I extract result and fetalMovements but I get nil for date and number_of_movement.

```
NSDictionary *Fetaljson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GetMovURL options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *fetalmovDic = [Fetaljson objectForKey:@"result"];
NSDictionary *MovmenteDic= [fetalmovDic objectForKey:@"fetalMovements"];
NSDictionary *DAteDic = [MovmenteDic objectForKey:@"date"]; 
NSMutableArray *array = [DAteDic valueForKey:@"number_of_movement"];
```

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:`?

Comment: You get `nil` because there is neither `date` nor `number_of_movement` directly inside `fetalMovements`... You need to first get one of the movements, e.g. `"10|22|2014-08-04 00:00:00"` and then look for those fields in it...

Comment: Thank you slazyk for reply, this is exactly my question. how to get the first movements because its not static e.g. "10|22|2014-08-04 00:00:00" for every user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you need (Without `NSString` to `NSDate` pasing):

```
NSDictionary *Fetaljson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GetMovURL options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *dict = [Fetaljson valueForKeyPath:@"result.fetalMovements"];
for (id key in [dict allKeys]) {
    NSString *numberOfMovement = dict[key][@"number_of_movement"];
    NSLog(@"Your pair: %@, %@", key, numberOfMovement);
}
```

Comment: It's unsafe to check an error instance returned by reference; instead, check the method's return value. From Apple's *Error Handling Programming Guide*: "Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure by directly returning `nil` or `NO`, you should always check that the return value is `nil` or `NO` before attempting to do anything with the `NSError` object."

Comment: You are right. I fixed my answer. Is now satisfactory for you?\ I took this solution from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866403/passing-data-from-local-file-using-json I think you should write the comment below.

Comment: Actually, the class method you posted is irrelevant to the OP's question, and there's no need to redundantly post the JSON file from the original question. I'd recommend deleting everything from 'Importing the JSON file' down. Also, *information* is misspelled -- why not just abbreviate that as `info`?

Comment: Thank you jlehr and Szu, I appreciate your help. I want to extract the request from php server, I don't have local JSON file. any idea?

Comment: first line may misled you. Check now my answer.

Comment: thank you Szu, I use for loop to get all record and it working fine, but its not order as it in database, [dict allKeys] sometime its get value for record num 11 then 20, 15, how to order the result key=1,2,3,4,..?

Comment: If my answer solves your problem then accept it. You cannot get keys like 1, 2, 3. NSDictionary is an unordered set of key-value pair.